# Плохо различимый цвет шрифта при входе в любой чат заблокированным участником

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, чат

[image: Шрифт забаненному]

Будучи заблокированным, проверял функционал Stack Overflow для забаненных участников на предмет дефектов — вроде бы больше ничего не обнаружил.

Comment: Заблокированный юзер должен страдать! :)

Comment: Эм.. При входе в заблокированный чат тоже...

Comment: @Qwertiy нечего суваться куда не надо!

Comment: @alexolut, если меня или кого-нибудь ещё сейчас заблокируют, надо обязательно будет посмотреть в условном Firebug стили для плохо видимых элементов у заблокированных участников. На Stack Overflow некоторые элементы также по мне как плохо различимых цветов, поэтому я взял одну тему с userstyles, подкорректировал, сменил цвета у svg-спрайтов — получилась [**вот такая тема для личного пользования**](https://www.pastery.net/usaprd/). Спасибо.